# Theoretical question: removing the wrong entry with efibootmgr?

Tags: dual-boot, windows, uefi

Efibootmgr lists Ubuntu and Windows Boot Manager, as well as two other things that say UEFI (I'll update this with better info later, I'm on mobile). If I were to accidentally remove windows or the UEFI boot options, would I be able to get them back?

I just want to know how paranoid I should be about accidentally typing the wrong number.

Answer (score 2):

You could get them back, but only if you know the correct path to the boot loaders. Also, you might not be able to easily recover some types of boot entries, such as those for PXE-booting or booting legacy OSes, since `efibootmgr` doesn't give you a way to create such entries.

To add an entry with `efibootmgr`, you use a command something like this:

```
efibootmgr -c -d /dev/sdb -p 2 -l \\EFI\\newloader\\loadername.efi -L NewLoader
```

The options shown here are:

- `-c` -- Creates a new entry.
- `-d /dev/sdb` -- The entry refers to a file on `/dev/sdb`. (`/dev/sda` is the default.)
- `-p 2` -- The file is on partition 2. (`1` is the default.)
- `-l \\EFI\\newloader\\loadername.efi` -- This is the path to the loader file *on the ESP* (*not* in Linux). Note the doubled-up backslashes (`\\`) as path separators. Alternatively, you can use single backslashes if the entire path is enclosed in quotes. Some new versions of `efibootmgr` can use Unix-style forward slashes instead, but I'm not sure offhand whether these new versions are included in any Ubuntu version.
- `-L NewLoader` -- This is the name of the loader, as displayed in your firmware's boot manager menu.

You can get the last two items from the `efibootmgr -v` output. The first two items are encoded as device paths and long GUIDs, so it's easier to figure them out by locating your ESP based on its current mount entry in `/etc/fstab` or by searching for FAT partitions with `parted` or `blkid`.